# Binding list to Datagridview issue c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, datagridview

I have a list which is populated with data from a CSV file, but when I set that list to datagridview data source property, no data is shown. Can you suggest where I might have made a mistake?

### Here is my code

```
        var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);   // IEnumerable<string>
        var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());  // IEnumerable<string[]>
        var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
        {
            CSRName = data[6],
            CallStart = data[0],
            CallDuration = data[1],
            RingDuration = data[2],
            Direction = data[3],
            IsInternal = data[4],
            Continuation = data[5],
            ParkTime = data[7]
        }).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = users;
```

### EDIT

Now I did it this way instead, and the data is showing.

```
    var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);   // IEnumerable<string>
    var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(',').ToArray());  // IEnumerable<string[]>
    var users = csvLinesData.Select(data => new User
    {
        CSRName = data[12],
        CallStart = data[0],
        CallDuration = data[1],
        RingDuration = data[2],
        Direction = data[4],
        IsInternal = data[8],
        Continuation = data[10],
        ParkTime = data[18]
    }).ToList();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("CSRName",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("CallStart", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("CallDuration", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("RingDuration", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Direction", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("IsInternal", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Continuation", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ParkTime", typeof(string));

    DataRow dr = null;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["CSRName"] = user.CSRName;
        dr["CallStart"] = user.CallStart;
        dr["CallDuration"] = user.CallDuration;
        dr["RingDuration"] = user.RingDuration;
        dr["Direction"] = user.Direction;
        dr["IsInternal"] = user.IsInternal;
        dr["Continuation"] = user.Continuation;
        dr["ParkTime"] = user.ParkTime;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    //dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Have you set AutoGenerateColumns property to true??

Answer (score 0):

Bind your gridview to a BindingList, instead of List.

```
var bindlist = new BindingList<User>(users);
```

And then create a binding source and bind that to the gridview.

```
 var source = new BindingSource(bindlist, null);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```